# how can I leave only last 10 newest files in a dir using java?

Tags: java, file, filter, lambda

I want to write code with a method that get a `file path` and a `file name prefix`

and delete all files in that `dir path` with  that `file name prefix` except for the 10 newest files.

I wanted to use lambda (java 8)

but I'm not sure how ti filter 10 most recent files:

```
   public Optional<File> getLatestFileFromDir(String baseLineFileName) {
        File baseLineFile = new File(baseLineFileName);
        File dir = baseLineFile.getParentFile();
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return Arrays.asList(dir.listFiles()).stream()
                .filter(file -> isNameLikeBaseLine(file, baseLineFile.getName()))
                .max(new Comparator<File>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
                        int answer;
                        if (o1.lastModified() == o2.lastModified()) {
                            answer = 0;
                        } else if (o1.lastModified() > o2.lastModified()) {
                            answer = 1;
                        } else {
                            answer = -1;
                        }
                        return answer;
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please find a full working example which

- create thirdy dummy files with different last modified timestamp
- create a list of those files
- shuffle them to show that the comparator is working as expected
- delete or show the files, except the ten files with to most recent last modified timestamp

.

```
public class KeepTopTenFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
        createDummyFiles(files);
        Collections.shuffle(files);

        files.stream()
                .filter((File p) -> p.getName().matches("foobar_.*"))
                .sorted(getReverseLastModifiedComparator())
                .skip(10)
                // to delete the file but keep the most recent ten
                // .forEach(x -> ((File) x).delete());
                // or display the filenames which would be deleted
                .forEach((x) -> System.out.printf("would be deleted: %s%n", x));
    }

    private static Comparator<File> getReverseLastModifiedComparator() {
        return (File o1, File o2) -> {
            if (o1.lastModified() < o2.lastModified()) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (o1.lastModified() > o2.lastModified()) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        };
    }

    private static void createDummyFiles(ArrayList<File> files) throws IOException {
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int filesToCreate = 30;
        for (int i = 0; i < filesToCreate; i++) {
            long lastModified = timestamp + 5 * i;
            String fileName = String.format("foobar_%02d", i);
            File file = new File(fileName);
            file.createNewFile();
            file.setLastModified(lastModified);
            files.add(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a custom comparator `.sorted(getReverseLastModifiedComparator())` in the example we could use `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(File::lastModified).reversed())`

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays.asList(dir.listFiles()).stream()
            .filter(file -> isNameLikeBaseLine(file, baseLineFile.getName()))
            .sorted(new Comparator<File>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
                    int answer;
                    if (o1.lastModified() == o2.lastModified()) {
                        answer = 0;
                    } else if (o1.lastModified() > o2.lastModified()) {
                        answer = -1;
                    } else {
                        answer = 1;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }
            }).limit( 10 );
```

Comment: The answer is not correct, as `limit(10)` would return the ten oldest files. The returned values in the Comparator should be swapped (o1.lastModified() > o2.lastModified() to return -1 and the default return 1) to return the values in reverse order and `limit(10)` should be replaced by `skip(10)` to skip the ten newest files and return the remaining files to be deleted.

Comment: @user1065869 I admit I didn't really look closely at `compare`.

Comment: @SubOptimal Thanks for checking. But skip skips 10, which isn't guaranteed to leave 10. But changing the order of compare should do the trick.

Comment: As the stream should return the values in descending order (see my first comment), the first ten elements are the files with themost recent last modified timestamp. So we need to skip them and return the remaining files.

Comment: @SubOptimal Ah, the eternal dubious meaning of "filter" ("want to filter 10 most recent files"). With "filter coffee" you want the coffee, with a "gold filter" (dentist!) you want the gold. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using limit(10); after sorting in correct way

Another way is to use skip(10) and forEach( f--> removefile(f) ). I think it better fits.

Comment: but i want the inverse selection. I want to leave these 10 files. and delete all other (don't know how many)

Comment: change comparator for inverse selection